# What does this mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function fkey(a) {
    a || (a = {});
    if (!a.fkey) a.fkey = $("input[name='fkey']").attr("value");
    return a
}
```

I guess `a` is actually a function, but how to understand `(!a.fkey)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is not a function, it's an object.

The `a.fkey` is accessing a member of the `a` object. The `!` in front means that if the member does not exist or the value is falsy, the expression evaluates to `true` and the `fkey` member is set to `$("input[name='fkey']").attr('value');`, which can also be accomplished with `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`

Answer (score 2):

`a` is an object in this case, it's setting the `.fkey` property on it if it isn't set (or is falsy) already.

For SO chat, this allows the `fkey` input to either be provided or gotten from the page, it's a hidden input at the bottom of your page, populated with a value used to authenticate your request and such.

Currently it's *always* pulling from the DOM, so really this function just adds the property, it *would* leave it alone if it were provided though.

Comment: @Mark - please don't correct the answer - I explicitly mean "falsy", **not** "false".

Comment: That is so weird that we both used the same terminology for it.   ;-)

Comment: @Jacob - That's the common term afaik: http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+falsy

Comment: Sorry, never heard the term before so assumed it was a typo. You learn something every day ;)

Answer (score 0):

The function you posted adds a member named `fkey` to `a` if it did not already exist. The `!a.fkey` part essentially means "does not already exist" (this works because once assigned, the member does not evaluate to `false`).

Answer (score 0):

The function takes an `object` and adds an `fkey` property to it, which will be the value of
`<input name="fkey">` field.

For example:

`<input name="fkey" value="WATCH ME HERE">`

```
var temp = {};    // make a new object
fkey(temp);       // expand it with fkey's value
alert(temp.fkey); // WATCH ME HERE
```